# Cannot open CSV file in phtml template

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, phtml

I have the next problem:

I have my custom module for testing and i try open a csv file and import products.

My problem is that i can open a csv in a file.php and show data but in file.phtml i cant open csv file.

My code is this:

```
            $file="ejemplo_productos.csv";
            if (file_exists($file)){
                $gestor = fopen($file, "r");
                var_dump($gestor);
            }
                while (($data = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                    echo 'Importing product: '.$data[0].'<br />';
                    foreach($data as $d)
                    {
                        echo $d.'<br />';
                    }
                    $num = count($data);

                    $row++;   
                }
                fclose($gestor);
```

This code in file.php works fine, in file.phtml dont found.

Help me, Ty!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should look to move that into a controller or a block instead of the template its self. You need to make sure that you have the file in the correct place since you mention it works in your .php but not .phtml files, but you are using a relative path.

**Example**

`$filename = Mage::getBaseDir() . "/var/uploads/ejemplo_productos.csv`

This assumes you have put the file in your Magento var/uploads folder, you can correct the path from there however.

Your processing logic can move to the block level, then your template can call it.

**Block**:

```
public function getProductsFromCsv()
{
$filename = Mage::getBaseDir() . "/var/uploads/ejemplo_productos.csv
// Parse CSV here 
return $processedCsvArray; 
}
```

**Template**:

```
$data = $this->getProductsFromCsv();
foreach($data as $data) { /* output csv data as required or process further */
```

Comment: Where you put // Parse CSV here, What I have to put? Because i have 3000 products in the file csv

Comment: The parse is simply the opening of the file and reading in from csv. Likely what you currently have as a while loop can fit in there, populating into the $processedCsvArray

Comment: It's work fine now! Ty ;)